# Cache CSS , JavaScript , Image Spring Boot (+Thymeleaf)

Tags: javascript, css, thymeleaf

I'm building a web Spring Boot with Thymeleaf. I saw Thymeleaf always load all resource when I refresh or change page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdfHB.png)
[Thymeleaf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdfHB.png).
How can I cache resources from memory, similar to .Net MVC framework which can do it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNyvG.png)
[DotNetMVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNyvG.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this.

1. using WebMVCConfig.
2. using application.properties file

WebMVCConfig.

Create template resolver as this.

```
@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver()
{
    FileTemplateResolver templateResolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode( "HTML5" );
    templateResolver.setCacheable( Boolean.FALSE );
    templateResolver.setOrder( 1 );
    return templateResolver;
}
```

Application properties

add following line to application.properties file

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache: false
```

Comment: Thanks @Supun Dharmarathne, but it doesn't work for both of them. I get error : org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "C:\user\login").

Answer (score 0):

I saw other solution

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("/resources/")                  
                        .setCachePeriod(31556926);
            }
        };
    }
```

For reference: [headers-cache-control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-cache-control)
But still doesn't work for me. I am using Spring Boot Security also.